# Nomenclature of an organic compound with multiple substituents

Tags: organic-chemistry, nomenclature

[image]

what is the IUPAC system of naming a compound with multiple substituents? I am not sure if the name should be something like 3-ethyne-1-hydroxy-5-yne-2-pentanone. This structure contains 2 triple bonds, 1 carbonil group and 1 hydroxy group. So which substituent I take first to name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow the freely available flow chart and examples of the [Brief Guide](https://www.degruyter.com/document/doi/10.1515/pac-2019-0104/html) or its 4 page summary of IUPAC's Blue Book compiled in the [resources page](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/37303/resources-for-learning-chemistry/155812#155812) (section chemical nomenclature):

[image]